# Android how to prevent soft keyboard and define buttons as an input to textEdits

Tags: java, android, button, keyboard, textedit

I have two textEdits and a bunch of buttons that serve as an input to these two textEdits (similar to a calculator). How do I prevent the softkeyboard from appearing when the use presses on any of the textEdits and allow my buttons to input the values as they are pressed.

To summarize:

I want to prevent system soft keyboard from appearing when textEdit is active.

I want my buttons to be the input source to my two textEdits.

Finally, how do I know in my buttons listener which TextEdit is active so that I can append the number pressed.

The following picture shows an example:

[image]

Comment: tried editable:false ?

Comment: tried it and does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

first you need to disable the input method for your textEdit as follow:

```
yourTextEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

the above will prevent the soft keyboard from being an input to your textEdit

They in your button listener `.setOnClickListener` you can identify which textEdit is active by checking `yourTextEdit.isFocused()` and do whatever you want to do in your listener.

Hope this helps someone out there

Answer (score 1):

1) you can try it using editexts default methods like :

```
android:editable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

2) on your other button click you can set text to edittext like :

```
editText.setText(btnValue);
```

Comment: good. but how would I know which textEdit the user is typing to? ... I want the button to input the value to the textEdit that the user is activating for input

Comment: you can addTextChangeListener but if you wish to allow edittext to be edit then you have to remove above tags based on your condition